# Getting the required data from a Nested Json using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a nested JSON as shown below :

```
{
"ok": true,
"messages": [
    {
        "bot_id": "G45667S9F",
        "type": "message",
        "text": "garbage123",
        "user": "SDFGHJ123",
        "ts": "1555007738.345800"
    },
    {
        "client_msg_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "type": "message",
        "text": "completed task123",
        "user": "SDFGHJ123",
        "ts": "1555007735.345700"
    },
    {
        "client_msg_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "type": "message",
        "text": "sdfghnjmxcvbnmsd",
        "user": "SDFGHJ123",
        "ts": "1555007721.345500"
    },
    {
        "bot_id": "G45667S9F",
        "type": "message",
        "text": "garbage123",
        "user": "SDFGHJ123",
        "ts": "1555007451.345300"
    },
    {
        "client_msg_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "type": "message",
        "text": "starting task123",
        "user": "SDFGHJ123",
        "ts": "1555007449.345200"
    },
    {
        "bot_id": "G45667S9F",
        "type": "message",
        "text": "garbage123",
        "user": "SDFGHJ123",
        "ts": "1554960212.319800"
    }
],
"has_more": true
}
```

I want to extract all the text field which has the key "client_msg_id" but not the text field which has "bot_id"

Expected output : ["completed task123", "sdfghnjmxcvbnmsd", "starting task123" ]

The below is what I tried

```
text1 = json.loads(r1.data)
object_list = text1['messages']
chill = [obj['text'] for obj in object_list]
print(chill)
```

This prints all the text fields from JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if `'client_msg_id'` is in `obj` dictionary keys

```
chill = [obj['text'] for obj in object_list if 'client_msg_id' in obj]
```

Comment: note: no need for `in obj.keys()`. `in obj` is enough, and using `keys()` in python 2 degrades the peformance drastically. Don't use it. edited post.

Comment: The question is specifically tagged with Python 3, FWIW

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dictionary is assigned to a `data`, you can do.

```
valid = [message['text'] for message in data['messages'] if "client_msg_id" in message and 'bot_id' not in message]
print(valid)
#['completed task123', 'sdfghnjmxcvbnmsd', 'starting task123']
```

Here you iterate through all messages, and only read the value with key `text` for the messages which has key `client_msg_id` but doesn't have the key `bot_id`

Answer (score -1):

You can add and `if` condition to the end of of a list comprehension, like so:

```
[obj['text'] for obj in text1['messages'] if 'bot_id' not in obj.keys()]
```

Use that to test is an item should be included in your result list.

Comment: This gives exactly the wrong output `['garbage123', 'garbage123', 'garbage123']`

Comment: sorry - `not in`